# How can i do a grep count by using timestamp

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, grep

How can I do a `grep` count by using timestamp?

Example: If I have a file in which I search a value `xyz` everytime. The file gets updated regularly.

```
20121912-07:15:55 abc cbfr xyz
20121912-07:16:40 mni cbfr xyz
-----------
-----------
-----------


20121912-08:15:55 gty cbfr xyz
20121912-08:20:55 jui uio xyz
```

I want to find out the occurences of `xyz` after `20121912-08:15:55` which in this case should be `2`.

Doing a `grep -c "xyz" filename` reads the entire file and gives the result. I want to do it after the last update or using a timestamp.

Comment: Unfortunate choice for timestamp format.

Answer (score 2):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '$NF=="xyz"&&$1>="20121912-08:15:55"{x++;}END{print x}' file
```

Comment: didn't know awk would parse and compare timestamps; very neat one!

Comment: Dates are not in lexicographically descending order, e.g. 20122011-08:15:55 is "greater" than 20121912-08:15:55.

Comment: @Rubens: no it does not work, awk will perform a string comparison which, in this case, is not the same as a date comparison. It would work if the date format were: YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to find the occurrences of pattern: 'xyz' where the date/time value is greater than or equal to a specified date/time: '20121912-08:15:55'. Here's what I'd do using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -v pattern="xyz" -v time="20121912-08:15:55" -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    stamp = convert(time)
}

$0 ~ pattern && convert($1) >= stamp {
    i++
}

END {
    print i
}

function convert(var) {

    x = "(....)(..)(..)-(..):(..):(..)"
    y = "\\1 \\3 \\2 \\4 \\5 \\6"

    return mktime(gensub(x,y,"",var))
}
```

Results:

```
2
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -v pattern="xyz" -v time="20121912-08:15:55" 'BEGIN { stamp = convert(time) } $0 ~ pattern && convert($1) >= stamp { i++ } END { print i } function convert(var) { return mktime(gensub(/(....)(..)(..)-(..):(..):(..)/,"\\1 \\3 \\2 \\4 \\5 \\6","",var)) }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack but just `grep` for the earliest date you want and print all lines after that using `-A` and then pipe to `grep -c xyz`:

```
$ fgrep -A 100 '20121912-08:15:55' file | fgrep -c 'xyz'
2
```

Note: `fgrep` is just fixed string `grep` as you're not using `regex` patterns, it's the same as doing `grep -F`.

As less hacky way would be to use `sed` to print all lines from the date, this way you wouldn't need to make sure the value to `-A` would cover the length of the file:

```
$ sed -n '/20121912-08:15:55/,$p' file | fgrep -c 'xyz'
2
```

This assumes of course you file is in sorted order by timestamps if it's not then:

```
$ sort file | sed -n '/20121912-08:15:55/,$p' | fgrep -c 'xyz'
2
```

Comment: 3 questions: a,what happens if the file is not sorted by timestamp? b, how about a line starting with 20121912-08:10:10? c, what if there are many many lines after 20121912-08 line?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell sed to print lines from a file given a range (start and stop point) - the range can be regex or line number notation.

For your need this should do it:

```
$ sed -n '/20121912-08:15:55/,$p' input.txt | grep -c xyz
```

Here the start point is given by the date, treated as a regular expression and the end point is the last line symbol `$`. `p` tells sed to print the lines within the range given. The `-n` option to sed tells it to not print the lines that it is processing.

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from Kent's answer, here's some Perl that manipulates the odd timestamp into YYYYMMDD format:

```
ts="20121912-08:15:55" patt="xyz" perl -lane  '
    BEGIN {
        ($wanted_ts = $ENV{ts}) =~ s/^(....)(..)(..)/$1$3$2/;
        $pattern = qr{$ENV{patt}};
    }
    ($this_ts = $F[0]) =~ s/^(....)(..)(..)/$1$3$2/;
    $count++ if $this_ts ge $wanted_ts and /$pattern/;
    END {print $count}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, quickly written one :

```
 grep xyz filename | sed -r 's/^([^ ]+).*/ 20121912-08:15:55 <= \1/' | sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1\3\2/g' | sed 's/[-:]//g' | bc | grep 1 | wc -l
```

It's pretty ugly (I'm not a sed nor command line master) and may probably be shortened, but it's a way to do it. Explanation below :

```
  grep xyz filename                                  //gets all interseting lines
| sed -r 's/^([^ ]+).*/ 20121912-08:15:55 <= \1/'    //transform them into 
                                                       //comparison with the 
                                                       //date you want
| sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1\3\2/g' //invert day and month
| sed 's/[-:]//g'                                    //remove separators
| bc                                                 //ask bc result 
| grep 1                                             //get true results only
| wc -l                                              //and finally count them
```

For last line of your example, the steps would give :

```
20121912-08:20:55 jui uio xyz                  //grep 'xyz'
20121912-08:15:55 <= 20121912-08:20:55         //sed
20121219-08:15:55 <= 20121219-08:20:55         
20121219081555 <= 20121219082055               
1                                              //result from bc
```

HTH

Comment: Downvoting is fine, when explained... ?